# Will freezing preserve invertase

Tags: storage, candy

The age deterioration of the enzyme action of invertase is slowed under cold storage.  I am wondering though, with freezing stop/slow it even more, or will it damage the enzymes beyond normal aging rates?

Answer (score 1):

A quick google return some scientific papers saying that the process is slowed down.

For example : "...Freezing resulted in a [marked decrease](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1365-2621.1969.tb10370.x) in invertase activity...."

How does it affect candy storage? I don't know enough to help; you could try a batch.